# Libgdx project tango

Tags: libgdx, google-project-tango

Has any one tried using libgdx on project tango? I have the problem updating the camera based on pose data. I am using the following code:

```
conversionQuaternion = new Quaternion(M_SQRT_2_OVER_2,
        -M_SQRT_2_OVER_2, 0.0f, 0.0f); // This is used to convert from start
                                        // of service coordinates to open gl
                                        // coordinates quaternion

position.set((float) pose.translation[0], (float) pose.translation[2],
            -(float) pose.translation[1]);
rotation.set((float) pose.rotation[0], (float) pose.rotation[1],
            (float) pose.rotation[2], (float) pose.rotation[3]);

rotation.mulLeft(conversionQuaternion); 

Assets.cam.up.set(0, 1, 0);
Assets.cam.direction.set(0, 0, -1);
Assets.cam.position.set(position);
Assets.cam.rotate(rotation);
Assets.cam.update();
```

Comment: had tried to integrate libgdx 3d view on Project tango's augmented reality.

Comment: Did you get anywhere using libgdx as the 3D framework for a Project Tango AR app?

Comment: Can you share how you made it work, if it did?